# How to import outlook category into MS access database table?

Tags: ms-access, outlook

I'am trying to import outlook emails from a folder into a database but I need to have a column for the category. how do I include this into the database?

Comment: Category is attribute assigned by you? Have you tried appending to an existing table with this Category field? Then entering the value for each record?

Comment: Yes, I've created category so tag it to the specific project name. No, i could add this to the table. Just imported data using New data source selecting outlook folder, then selected "Link to the data source through the linked table. The output is with standard columns.

My apologies I'm doing it for the first time.

Comment: If you are linking then I see no way to assign a category value to each record within that link. If subject line has nothing more than project name (or better, a project number), could possibly therefore link in a query to a master table of project names/numbers where a Category field is populated.

Comment: Is there a way to add a field to a linked table, this field would then fetch the category that is assigned to the email?

Comment: Only if you add a field to the source and since the source is Outlook, I doubt can do that.